# Household member last name shows twice

Tags: contacts, households

When we look at the household member is and pull up a record, it shows the household member last name twice, eg Bartlett,Bartlett. However when you click on this it shows the proper name, eg Peter Barlett.

Any ideas[image: Household member is example]

[image: Actual Record name example once clicked]

Comment: Version and platform, please.

Comment: Drupal and Version 4.7

Comment: Do you have any extensions or custom code installed?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this after looking at the import of data. Remedy was to highlit the double name and click edit then save. it reset the data correctly. Did this via a bulk update

Comment: Great you got this fixed - you can accept your own answer!